# Additional margin when filling XFA forms with itext7 instead of itext5

Tags: itext7

I'm upgrading a simple tool to fill XFA PDF forms with itext. The idea is simple, all formatting related information (font name / font size / aligning / margins / etc) is stored in the form. I only put plain text in he form.

In itext5

```
String fieldname = "myField";

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(templatePath);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(outputPath));
pdfStamper.getAcroFields().setField(fieldname, "This is the field filled with iText5");
acroFields.setFieldProperty(fieldname , "bordercolor", BaseColor.RED, null);
pdfStamper.setFormFlattening(true);
```

[image]

In itext7 (8.0.2)

```
String fieldname = "myField";

try (final PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(new File(templatePath)));
                                        final PdfDocument stamper = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(new File(outputPath)))) {
            final PdfAcroForm arcoform = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(stamper, true);

final PdfFormField pdfField = arcoform.getField(fieldname);
pdfField.setValue("This is the field filled with iText7");
pdfField .getFirstFormAnnotation().setBorderWidth(1).setBorderColor(ColorConstants.RED);
arcoform.flattenFields();
```

[image]

For some reason there is an offset in the itext7 version. It only happens with multiline fields, with the "normal" fields, there is no extra offset. Is there a way I can fix this?